# What are the preferable icon and screenshot image sizes to submit a new firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am looking to submit a new firefox addon, but not aware of all image sizes to submit along with .xpi file.

Comment: thanks a ton for your reply Noitidart. I found these links at last.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Publishing/Policies_and_Guidelines/Marketplace_screenshot_criteria

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/icons

Answer (score 1):

64, 48, 32, 16

- 64 - Used as addon icon, in install, and addon manager. And also on AMO listing
- 48 - used in some places of browser as addon icon
- 32 - used as the icon in the tristrip/hamburger menu
- 16 - used as the icon in the nav bar